# Authorize.net and paypal

Tags: paypal, authorize.net

I am trying to implement paypal express-checkout with authorize.net.

I already did the Authorize.net process

1. login with my sandbox account
2. Account option
3. Digital payment solutions
4. PayPal (sign up)
5. login with paypal sandbox
6. grant
7. redirected to authorize.net
8. status pending after more than 3 days.

I tried to gave access to authorize.net in paypal but when I entered the authorize.net Api Login it told me tha is invalid.

have somebody else had the same problem?
Do I need to add something else to the api Login?

Thanks id advance for your help

Comment: Did you try it iin the sandbox first?

Comment: Yes, I am working with the sandbox in both sites.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else has this problem.

I was using my sand box accounts in authorize.net and paypal.com

in paypal I had 2 business accounts one of them was not able to add authorize.net in "Manage Third Party Access" thats why was not working.